# ¿Cómo puedo clonar un dump .sql de Drupal en otro PC de desarrollo?

Tags: mysql, drupal

Buen día!

Necesito clonar en mi equipo un proyecto de Drupal. Estoy intentando instalar el dump de la base de datos usando MySQL Workbench, y cuando está realizando la import, aparece este error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 4528: MySQL server has gone away
Operation failed with exitcode 1
16:53:40 Import of F:\drupal.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

"MySQL server has gone away" suele aparecer cuando el servicio no está en ejecución. Pero en este caso sí lo está. De hecho, probé a restaurar el .sql de otro proyecto y lo corrió con total normalidad.

A qué se deberá el problema? Quedo atenta.

Gracias!

Comment: Chequea este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474922/error-2006-hy000-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Excelente! En esa pregunta se resolvió mi problema. Resulta que la directiva de mi _my.ini_ estaba configurada así: `max_allowed_packet=1M`. Yo cambié el _1M_ por _128M_, y restauró correctamente el dump! Gracias Alan!

Comment: De nada @NicoleJuli